# If statement for wordpress MIME type post attachment

Tags: php, wordpress, mime-types, mime

I am trying to create a if else statement for checking if the attachment is an audio file or not.

Could anyone assist in this please. I am using the wordpress get_post_mime_type function

```
if (get_post_mime_type($post->ID) == 'audio/mpeg') { 
    echo 'this is audio';
}
else {
    echo 'this aint audio';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is inside the wordpress loop.

Comment: What does `var_dump(get_post_mime_type($post->ID));` output?

Comment: This is what i get on var dump: string(0) ""

Comment: The question is how can i get this to work. If i go to a post that has a audio attachment, it does not echo in this is audio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

Its working in mine.

```
$attachment_mime = wp_check_filetype(wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID) );

if ( $attachment_mime['type'] == 'audio/mpeg') { 
    echo 'this is audio';
}
else {
    echo 'this aint audio';
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: When i var_dump $attachment_mime i get the following: array(2) { ["ext"]=> bool(false) ["type"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: @Zackskeeter you dont need to var_dump this one. you can also use file name e.g file.mp3 instead of wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID) in above code.

Comment: So why when i go var_dump($attachment_mime['type'] ); i get: bool(false)

Comment: Yeah i have, still doesnt echo the right thing when on a post that has audio :(

Comment: can you give me the code that gives only file name e.g. filename.mp3/ file.jpg  ...? i will trying with your code. why i am asking this because it is completely working in mine..

Comment: I think that there is somthing wrong with the system, this should be working. I think im going to have to rewrite the loop

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one also.

```
File Type: <?php echo $attachment->post_mime_type; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo get_post_mime_type(); ?>
```

Thanks